# How to get rendered XHTML from a Wicket panel

Tags: xhtml, wicket, panel

Users of my Wicket application should be able to edit some of the panels' output (X)HTML. There will be a button or link on each panel that, when clicked, will get the rendered content and use/open an editor such as TinyMCE.

I think I want some sort of `getRenderedXTML()` method for the panel, but have no clue how to get the rendered output programmatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can likely get the generated html just before it's sent to the browser, but this is a bad approach as reconnecting the edited html back the the generating fragments will be painful if not impossible.

Rather than actually trying to edit the dynamic markup, make the user-editable stuff part of the data.  Show it in a `Label` and use `setEscapeModelStrings(false)` to allow the label to properly render the html fragment.  On click of your link, replace that label with a textarea with tinymce behavior attached.

There is a some tinymce support in [wicketstuff-core](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core) that can help with this, and this [Wicket by Example article](http://wicketbyexample.com/wicket-tinymce-some-advanced-tips/) shows a bit of how to use it, though it may be a bit out-of-date, and references document locations no longer available.